# Best practice for "Coding to interfaces" and Business Entities?

Tags: design-patterns, class-design

Should business entities be abstracted away using interfaces and/or base-classes so that when you pass them around you use only the interfaces/base-classes? (this is what we have been doing).

Or should entities not be abstracted using interfaces and you should use inheritence only when necessary?

The reason I ask this question, is that I have always abstracted away all parts of my application code using interfaces as far as possible. This made it easy for me to perform unit tests using mocks, etc. In addition, by using the interfaces, I could make sure that only the factory classes actually referenced projects containing the implementation and all others (eg: Business Logic Layer) only referenced the project containing all the interfaces.

The above has worked well until now. But now, we need to expose some of our business methods via WCF. The business methods used to return interfaces, but now that I am trying to reuse the same method and expose it via WCF, WCF does not like the fact that I am using and returning interfaces as part of the service method arguments.

Now I could try and fix the problem using KnownTypes and ServiceKnownTypes, but it got me thinking that if I did not use interfaces for the business entities part of my application, I would not have come across this problem.

So I was wondering if there is a best practice when it comes to a new project: should you or should you not have interfaces for all your business entities?

Comment: I've seen many recommend against interfaces over business entities. And sending your business entities over the wire is probably a bad idea either.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually tell WCF to use your interface across the wire, so it's not a problem.

It's a setting in the Add Service Reference dialog.

What you're looking for is the option "Reuse types in referenced assemblies".

You want to make sure that your contracts are being used on both ends of the wire, so you'll need to make sure you've selected to reuse reference assemblies, and you need to make sure your assembly is in the reference assemblies list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx

To get around the base class having to know about the subclasses you could do something like this:

```
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public abstract class Shape
{
    static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
        //do some reflection here to look up all classes that extend Shape
        //and are serializable
        return results;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure you could use the same approach for an interface since it requires having a static method implementation.

Comment: This works when you are returning actual classes as part of your WCF implementation. But when you return or use interfaces as part of your method signature, you end up with having to decorate a ton of the code with KnownTypeAttribute and that is what my question is about. (in addition, there is no easy way to add the KnownTypeAttribute other than by manual inspection of the classes)

Comment: @Rajah I see what you mean, I'll update my answer with an approach for that